# Is there a way to access a file stored in amazon S3 in Alexa Skills Kit?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I am making a random fact Alexa skill, and want to access the data for all the facts from a csv or JSON file. I was hoping I can store this file in S3 and access it in my skill but I haven't found a way to do this. Is this possible? If not is there another way to access a file in my skill?

Comment: How does one access a file without an API?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Alexa-hosted skill, you get access to an Amazon S3 bucket for media storage. You can use the following S3 actions: GetObject, PutObject, DeleteObject, ListBucket, ListAllMyBuckets.

So if this is the case and you are using an Alexa-hosted skill and you want to access the assigned S3 bucket, check out the following documentation on how to access those files:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-media-files.html

For accessing your own personal S3 bucket from a hosted skill, check out the following documentation on how to do that:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-personal-aws.html